# 3 Children/teenagers move to an old castle, as a foster home, due to an accident

Tags: story-identification, books

I think I read this book in about 2009/2010ish. I am pretty sure this is strictly a fantasy book.

I don't remember much, except these 3 kids/teenagers have this accident happen to them where they live, and have to move to a foster home. I remember it being described as an old castle on top of a hill, in front of a lake, close to a little village.

Also the "master" of this old foster home, is this old guy who kinda gives out this "wizard" vibe.

This is very early in the book, and before they go out on their adventure.  I don't remember what adventure they go out on. I just remember it was just a setup for the story of an adventure.

---

This is not *Harry Potter*, *Narnia*. or *A Series of Unfortunate Events*.

Comment: What about this is science fictional or fantasy?

Comment: It is none of those. Unfortunately.

@Valorum I remember the book being fantasy. But nothing in the parts i remembered was fantasy.